# MySQL update each record based on data at the same table

Tags: mysql, sql-update

I have one table in MySQL database (just example)

```
CREATE  TABLE test.Names (
    id INT NOT NULL ,  
    salary INT NULL ,  
    name VARCHAR(45) NULL , 
    tmpl INT,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`) ,  
    UNIQUE INDEX `id_UNIQUE` (`id` ASC)
);
```

I have these records

```
id,   salary, name, tmpl
1,    10,     John, null 
2,    20,     Pat,  null 
3,    30,     Jane, null
```

I'd like update the table by this simple calculation for each person

```
salary of each person/Sum(salary)*100
```

So the result should be

```
id,   salary, name, tmpl
1,    10,     John, 16.67 
2,    20,     Pat,  33.33 
3,    30,     Jane, 50
```

How to perform this by one SQL query? Or what is the best approach (I assume the real table will have >100 000 rows)

Comment: I don't follow. It looks like your sample output is the result of the `tmpl` column being `salary * 1.6`.

Comment: It is because the sum of everybody's salary is 60.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a separate SELECT statement to get the total salary - either put that in a variable, or cross-join this with your existing table. Then you have the sum available for each individual record.

This SQL code suffices:

```
SET @sum_salaries = (SELECT SUM(salary) FROM test.Names);

UPDATE test.Names
SET tmpl = salary/@sum_salaries * 100;
```

No need for a join, even. Simpler this way and probably faster.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
SET @SallarySum = (SELECT SUM(salary) FROM TableName);

UPDATE Names t1
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT id, (Salary / @SallarySum) * 100 tmpl
    FROM Names
) t2 ON t1.Id = t2.Id
SET t1.tmpl = t2.tmpl;
```

### Here is a [SQL Fiddle DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/aa089/1).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
update `test`.`Names`
 set tmpl = salary / (select sum(salary) from `test`.`Names`) * 100
where tmpl is null --for multiple times execution
```

You may have to change tmpl column to double datatype.